# Derivation of a vector equation

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I am reading a derivation of conditional multivariate distribution, I have checked many time the following equation, I think it is wrong. $u$ and $v$ are any vectors, and $A$ is symmetric matrix.

The source is from a online webpage: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gaussianprocess/node7.html
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&&u^TAu-2u^TAv+v^TAv=u^T Au-u^TAv-u^TAv+v^TAv
\nonumber \\
&=&u^TA(u-v)-(u-v)^TAv=u^TA(u-v)-v^TA(u-v)
\nonumber \\
&=&(u-v)^TA(u-v)=(v-u)^TA(v-u) 
\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Would any one confirm me this is wrong?

Comment: It's correct, the quantity on the far left equals the quantity on the far right of the equalities. Is there any step in particular you don't understand?

Comment: @Olivier Bégassat: Agree. The only non-trivial step is that $xAy = (xAy)^T$ since both LHS and RHS are one-dimensional.

Comment: @gt6989b, thank you! This is exactly what I neglected, indeed they are scalars, transpose only change the expression, not the number.